# rtl space added at end/beginning of line only in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

The block that says it should have no space at the beginning of the line has a space at the beginning on google chrome, but in IE and firefox it renders correctly.

This is like if I were to justify a paragraph and then the spaces would either be preserved at the end of the lines or the beginning... it's stupid... isn't supposed to be done...

Please prove me wrong or provide a work around.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p style="text-align: left; background-color: #faa; direction: rtl;"><span style="display: inline-block;">WHATEVER</span> <span style="display: inline-block; direction: ltr;">this should wrap up but have no space at the beginning when at the beginning the line</span> <span style="display: inline-block; direction: ltr;">this should wrap down,</span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: rtl beginning is at right, ltr beginning is at left. is this what's confusing you ?

Comment: What do you expect the writing direction to imply?